# navigating another page once you submit the form in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an HTML form that captures user's input and sends them to the database. What I would like to do is navigate another page like details page where you see all entered information automatically.

My approach was to submit the values to the database and navigate the details page with passing submitted id. Here is my TypeScript code:

```
submit() {
  this.participantService.add(this.participant).subscribe(participant => {
  this.alertifyService.success('participant successfully added');
}, error => {
  this.alertifyService.error('Problem occured!\n' + error);
});

this.router.navigate(['participants/participants-details', this.participant.id]);
}
```

However, this code is just sending the values to the database. It doesn't take me to the `details` page. What would be the way to accomplish this?

Comment: Put the "this.router.navigate" INTO subscribe function. Only if the participant is successfully added, and not before this, you navigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not waiting for data submit to complete before routing to details page. Move `router.navigate()` within `subscribe's` `success` callback.

```
submit() {
  this.participantService.add(this.participant).subscribe(participant => {
      this.alertifyService.success('participant successfully added');
      this.router.navigate(['participants/participants-details', this.participant.id]);
  }, 
  error => {
    this.alertifyService.error('Problem occured!\n' + error);
   });
}
```